# Liquid page.date filter not working in index.html

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm using Jekyll and Liquid tags to format a site. The "page.date" variable is working for the pages in my collection, but does not display the date on the index.html file in my root directory. This is the line of code:

```
<h6 class="tar">Last update: {{ page.date | date: "%A, %B %-d, %Y" }}</h6>
```

Is index.html special in some way? Is there a different variable I need to use to display the date for this page?

Comment: Are you trying to show the last update of the index or for each article on the homepage?

Comment: For each individual page, I want to display the date that file was changed. It's working for the other pages on my site (displaying "Last update: May 6, 2016"), but on index.html it just displays "Last update: "

Comment: Yes, because each article has the date of it set in its filename or in FrontMatter. Will it be okay if I post a solution to show on index.html the date of your last article?

Comment: Please! :) I was under the assumption the global "page.date" variable meant it was getting the date from the file itself. I essentially want the display date to autoupdate if I make changes to a page. If there's some sort of auto tag I need to declare in the Front Matter, that's easy to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In contrary to collections (posts are collection) the page type needs a date in the front matter if you want to use it with `{{ page.date }}`.

Answer (score 0):

Restating my comment, the index page does not have a `date` variable attached to it, only posts have them. The date is set by the front matter `date` tag or, if this does not exist, it is taken from the post filename.

On the index page, to show the date of your last post, you have to use:

```
{{ site.posts.first.date | date: "%A, %B %-d, %Y" }}
```

Comment: Thanks! It doesn't quite solve my original issue -- I want to display the date that index.html itself was changed -- but this solution will come in handy for a different part of the navigation.